# Nginx Wordpress - <site> redirected you too many times

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm getting the above mentioned error and cannot pinpoint the cause:

I tried the solution:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

But without success. I think it's a problem with my nginx configuraton or a bug with wordpress?!?

I have other configurations in the `sites-enable` and I have tried to remove all of them and reload nginx without any success.

**Nginx Config:**

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name <site name>;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 http2;

    server_name <site name>;

    ssl on; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;
    # side note: only use TLS since SSLv2 and SSLv3 have had recent vulnerabilities
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /gctl_wp/;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name <site name>;

     location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }   

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
     }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your site as `http` but implemented it under `https`. You should set the correct site URL:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```